# Filter complex array by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
let array1 = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    genres: [
                        { id: 4, title: "qqqq" },
                        { id: 9, title: "zzzz" },
                        { id: 8, title: "eeee" },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    genres: [
                        { id: 2, title: "qwert" },
                        { id: 4, title: "asdf" },
                        { id: 5, title: "zxxcc" },
                    ],
                },
            ];

let array2 = [6, 8];
```

I need to filter array1 if genre id exists in array2.
So in output I should have only first element of array1.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `filter`, `some` and `includes`:

```js
let array1 = [{id:1,genres:[{id:4,title:"qqqq" },{id:9,title:"zzzz"},{id:8,title:"eeee" }]},
              {id:2,genres:[{id:2,title:"qwert"},{id:4,title:"asdf"},{id:5,title:"zxxcc"}]}];
let array2 = [6, 8];

let result = array1.filter(({genres}) => genres.some(({id}) => array2.includes(id)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` function.

One way to do it:

```
let result = array1.filter(el => {

    let output = false;
    el.genres.forEach( genre => {
        if (array2.includes(genre.id))
            output = true;
    });

    return output;
});
```

Comment: You can also add a break in the foreach loop to stop it if it already matched a value.